# Java - out of bounds exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am receiving the following error: `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` and I can't figure out why. Hopefully one of you knows a solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
static boolean palindromeCheck(String toBeChecked) {

    String reverse = "", inputWithoutSpaces = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < toBeChecked.length(); i++)
        inputWithoutSpaces += toBeChecked.charAt(i);

    for (int i = inputWithoutSpaces.length(); i > 0; i--) {

        if (inputWithoutSpaces.charAt(i) != ' ')
            reverse += inputWithoutSpaces.charAt(i);

    }

    return (inputWithoutSpaces == reverse) ? true : false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`charAt()` accepts indices from 0 to `length()-1`, not from 1 to `length()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `for (int i = inputWithoutSpaces.length(); i > 0; i--)`

Lets say the `inputWithoutSpaces` has length 10. i.e. indices `0` to `9`. In your loop you start counting from the index `inputWithoutSpaces.length()` which is `10`. Which does not exist. Hense the out of bounds exception.

Change it to `for (int i = inputWithoutSpaces.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)` so you count from `9` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your string has a specific length (lets say length: 5), but when you want to reverse iterate it you need to start from 4 and got down to 0. This means that you need to change your for loop and make it like this:

```
for (int i = inputWithoutSpaces.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```